# how do I decode sql inside query

Tags: php, sql

How can I do this query with php and sql?

```
$search = "cat"

SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '%$search%'
```

My username is base64 encoded

```
+----------------+
username
+----------------+
UG9zdGUgSsOh   = (cat)
+----------------+
U2FtcGFpbw==   = (dog)
+----------------+
RWxsZW4=       = (bird)
+----------------+
```

I tried that  `FROM_BASE64 and TO_BASE64`  but it didn't work or I didn't know how to do it

Comment: can you please tag your database system and post a 8mre] with table and data as text

Comment: and what code is executing this query?  You need to provide a [mcve] and tag with the programming language

Comment: What's the database? Different databases have different available functions.

Comment: If it's MySQL you want `WHERE FROM_BASE64(username) LIKE '%$search%'`.

Comment: Why are you encoding a column that you need to be able to search? This will require an expensive table scan, decoding every row.

Comment: _"I tried that FROM_BASE64 and TO_BASE64 but it didn't work or I didn't know how to do it"_ - we can't possibly tell what you might have done wrong, if you don't actually _show us_ what you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I found ..

```
$search = base64_encode($_POST['search']);
normal select from here
```